# Setting database with django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I created a db with such tracks.models:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and used

```
python manage.py sqall tracks
python manage.py syncdb
```

but then I changed models to

```
class Song(models.Model):
    songid = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and did

```
python manage.py sqall tracks
python manage.py syncdb
```

again. Output of sqall:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "tracks_song" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "songid" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "title" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "album_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "tracks_album" ("id")
)
;
CREATE INDEX "tracks_song_6781e42a" ON "tracks_song" ("album_id");

COMMIT;
```

syncdb:

```
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

But whenever I tried to access tracks.models.Song.all() it said:

```
OperationalError: no such column: tracks_song.songid
```

So I decided to

```
python manage.py flush
python manage.py sqall tracks
python manage.py syncdb
```

(same output)

But problem hasn't gone and there's still no such column: tracks_song.songid.
What's the problem behind it?

Comment: `python manage.py sqall tracks` means `python manage.py sqlall tracks`?

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py sqlall app-name` will only print SQL sentences, not create or change database structures, that is to say, it's used to check or tell you what django actually do in databases. Howerver, django version<1.7 doesn't track changes of **class** in models.py(newly increased or delete existed class could be detected and syncdb), but you can use **south**, or **django 1.7** to do such thing.

`python manage.py flush` will IRREVERSIBLY DESTROY all data, but not change tables in database.

**South**: http://south.aeracode.org/

**Django 1.7:** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#django-1-7-release-notes-under-development

you should also notice that if you only need an id field, class **Song** has a default **AutoField** **id**, just use **song.id** [Django models Quick Example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#quick-example)